# <identifier> expected error

Tags: java

So I have some code that I am tring to compile and I keep on getting this error:

```
3SATSolver.java:3: <identifier> expected
```

Here is the code. Am I simply not seeing something?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class 3SATSolver {

public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList values = new ArrayList<Boolean> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            Boolean d = new Boolean (args[i].charAt(0), Integer.parseInt(args[i].substring(1)));
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identifiers can't start with numerals in Java.

Comment: Thank you. A fresh set of eyes is sometimes the best thing.

Comment: Official rules on naming variables can be found at the bottom of this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Answer (score 1):

From [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java
>   digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.

You can use `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart` to check whether your starting letter is a valid identifier name.

```
char ch = '1';
boolean bool =  Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(ch);
System.out.println(bool);
```

Output = `False`